# How to disable glimpse update check request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I have noticed that glimpse checks whether there are any update on clientside via https://getglimpse.com/Api/Version/Check?Glimpse.Ado=1.7.3&Glimpse.AspNet=1.9.2&Glimpse=1.8.6&Glimpse.EF6=1.6.5&Glimpse.Mvc5=1.5.3&stamp=1450129430335&callback=glimpse.versionCheck.result .

http://prntscr.com/9edgdy

Also request couldnt be completed since link's certificate is not valid,

How can I disable it?

Comment: Same problem here.  Not only is the cert invalid, but many organizations do not like leaving any kind of "phone home" feature enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing config with different or loopback address for Url won't stop the Glimpse to make request version check request. I found that the version check is triggered from client side function `versionCheck`.

Here's a hot-fix I figured out how to disable the function `versionCheck` on glimpse object:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // A wierd fix to wait until glimpse is initialized.
    setTimeout(turnoffGlimpseVersionCheck, 100);
});

function turnoffGlimpseVersionCheck() {

    if (typeof glimpse == 'undefined') {
        console.log("glimpse not found!")
    }
    else {
        console.log(glimpse.settings);
        glimpse.versionCheck = function () { };
        console.log("glimpse updates turned off!!")
    }
}
```

It might not look good but it will just do the trick.

**Update**

Here's a updated and better version:

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        var isGlimpseLoaded = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
            var src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src');
            if (src == null) continue;
            if (src.indexOf('Glimpse.axd') > -1) {
                turnoffGlimpseVersionCheck();
                break;
            }
        }

    });

    function turnoffGlimpseVersionCheck() {
        glimpse.versionCheck = function () { };
        console.log('glimpse version check disabled!!')
    }

</script>
```

Comment: how can you sure about glimpse will be loaded in 100 ms?

Comment: Which is why i mentioned its a weird thing i did. :P

Answer (score 2):

Set `<add key="GlimpseVersionCheckAPIDomain" value="240.0.0.1" />` in `<appSettings>` of your `Web.config`.

This reconfigures any call that would have otherwise gone to getglimpse.com into a [black hole](https://superuser.com/questions/698244) instead. I tested this and confirmed zero phone-home attempts, and much quicker page loads now.

Relevant code is in: [Glimpse.Core/Resource/VersionCheckResource.cs](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/b2d9b35d1bdab4d7ddd483dcf1736a0d2879c5f5/source/Glimpse.Core/Resource/VersionCheckResource.cs)

```
var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GlimpseVersionCheckAPIDomain"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
        {
            domain = "getGlimpse.com";
        }

        return new CacheControlDecorator(OneDay, CacheSetting.Public, new RedirectResourceResult(@"//" + domain + "/Api/Version/Check{?packages*}{&stamp}{&callback}", data));
```